# auto close connection to database when PHP error during execution

Tags: php, mysql

I open MySQL connection in the beginning of script.php, there is a lot of code like opening files and query database, I close connection in the end of script Conn::disconnect();
I want call this function if an error is raising (fatal error for example) during the execution of script, and I can't handle all errors manually by try catch.

Comment: If you're closing it in the very end of the script - you may just remove the explicit closing and the behaviour would stay the same, since it's closed automatically anyway. PS: in what case would a fatal arise in your script? :-S

Comment: if you want something to happen when an error happens look into error handlers, shutdown handlers and Exceptions. But in general, you don't need to close the connection as PHP will do that anyway.

Comment: @Gordon♦: not in this case though, right?

Comment: @zerkms shutdown handler is always called so if the OP is desperate to close the connection manually, that's where it should go. It's just unneeded, like both of us and the dupe already pointed out.

Comment: @Gordon♦: and you have referred to a question with **REALLY CRAPPY** upvoted answer

Comment: @zerkms maybe, but at least I *did* reference one. Feel free to find a better one or put a better answer on it.